# Angular guard only works after delay

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a guard that prevents the user from going to a route if the active member is not loaded yet. Sometimes the active member is cached and the guard returns true immediately. When the observable emits true immediately the guard does not work, as if it never received the emitted 'true'. If I add a settimeout, everything works as expected. Why is the guard not working as I expect it to?

**Works**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    this.store.select(getActiveMember).pipe(filter(member => member != null), take(1)).subscribe(member => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.subject.next(true);
        }, 1000);
    })
    return this.subject;
}
```

**Doesn't work**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    this.store.select(getActiveMember).pipe(filter(member => member != null), take(1)).subscribe(member => {
        this.subject.next(true);
    })
    return this.subject;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an additional subject? I would just return `this.store.select(getActiveMember).pipe(filter(member => member != null), take(1), mapTo(true))`

Comment: Also, you might want to emit `false` on some occasion aswell

Comment: Your answer does seem to work, I don't know why using an extra subject made it behave any different. If you want to give that as an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using observables incorrectly here. The return here might fire before or after this.subject.next gets called, and you have no way of knowing one way or the other. Just return the observable directly and have the Observable resolve to true if the active member is not null. The code given by Marv could do that, but also just:

```
return this.store.select(getActiveMember)
    .map((member) => { return member != null && member != undefined})
```